# No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am upgrading my angular 4 to angular 6 application.  I am getting the following error while building my application.

```
error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["../../node_modules/@wtw/**/*"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["**/*.sp
ec.ts","**/*.stub.ts","test/**/*.ts"]'.

Error: error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["../../node_modules/@wtw/**/*"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["
**/*.spec.ts","**/*.stub.ts","test/**/*.ts"]'.
```

If I add  "**/*" to the include I get the following error and the above error dissapears.

```
ERROR in e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(3,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(6,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(10,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(12,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,

  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "type-definition"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },

  "include": [
    "../node_modules/@wtw/**/*",
    "**/*"
  ]
}
```

How do I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 6):

Because the error says 'exclude' paths were '["**/*.spec.ts","***/.stub.ts","test/**/*.ts"]', 
You need to have a *.ts file in the directory or sub directory, in which the tsconfig.app.json file resides with the include and exclude properties declared.

The "include" and "exclude" properties take a list of glob-like file patterns. The supported glob wildcards are:

- '*' matches zero or more characters (excluding directory separators)
- '?' matches any one character (excluding directory separators)
- '**/' recursively matches any subdirectory

If a segment of a glob pattern includes only * or .*, then only files with supported extensions are included (e.g. .ts, .tsx, and .d.ts by default with .js and .jsx if allowJs is set to true).

[You can refer this for more help](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)